# Flutter app build fails because of C++ widget that uses OpenCV 4.2.0

Tags: android, c++, ios, flutter, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV in a flutter app via a C++ widget using ffi and I tried following the instructions here https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/implementing-edge-detection-in-flutter/2020/1509/. The app is intended to work for both Android and iOS. I get the following error message when building the flutter app that uses the C++ widget which contains OpenCV and I'm not sure how to proceed next. Does anybody have any suggestions on what I should try next?

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':painting_processor:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/android/.cxx/Debug/56p5tm2z/arm64-v8a'
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native_painting_processor.dir/media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/ios/Classes/native_painting_processor.cpp.o
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/native_painting_processor.dir/media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/ios/Classes/native_painting_processor.cpp.o 
  /home/vlad/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/vlad/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/vlad/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Dnative_painting_processor_EXPORTS -I../../../../../include -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++17 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native_painting_processor.dir/media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/ios/Classes/native_painting_processor.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native_painting_processor.dir/media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/ios/Classes/native_painting_processor.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native_painting_processor.dir/media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/ios/Classes/native_painting_processor.cpp.o -c /media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/ios/Classes/native_painting_processor.cpp 
In file included from /media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/ios/Classes/native_painting_processor.cpp:2:
  In file included from ../../../../../include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:
  In file included from ../../../../../include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58:
  In file included from ../../../../../include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:81:
  In file included from ../../../../../include/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:11:
  /snap/flutter/current/usr/include/c++/9/memory:121:25: error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'uintptr_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information
    const auto __intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__ptr);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      /home/vlad/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja \
        -C \
        /media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/android/.cxx/Debug/56p5tm2z/arm64-v8a \
        native_painting_processor
    from /media/vlad/FEF8B6AEF8B66495/Projects/Me/MuseumApp/painting_processor/android

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```